# Why Get-AZRoleAssignment with ResourceName switch doesn't work?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to list who have Contributor permissions for specific resource name but when I want to use

```
Get-AZRoleAssignment -ResourceName "ResName"
```

I am receiving an error:

> "Get-AzRoleAssignment : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the
>   specified named parameters."

However, I am sure that the mentioned resource exists as I can see it when I run the command

```
get-azresource -ResourceGroupName "ResGroupName"
```

I was trying:

```
Get-AZRoleAssignment -ResourceName "ResName" -ResourceGroupName "ResGroupName"
```

but no luck.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, you must miss reading the description of the parameter `-ResourceName`.

> -ResourceName
>
> The resource name. For e.g. storageaccountprod. Must be used in
>   conjunction with ResourceGroupName, ResourceType, and
>   (optionally)ParentResource parameters.

So your PowerShell command should like this:

```
Get-AZRoleAssignment -ResourceName "ResName" -ResourceGroupName "ResGroupName" -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
```

You can change the type as you want. And if you just get the role Contributor, you can add the parameter `-RoleDefinitionName` with value `Contributor`.